# How to make an instance inside a custom object creation class method

Tags: python, object

I have a class

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(filename: str) -> None:
        with open(filename) as f:
            self.initialize(f)

    def initialize(self, stream)
        pass  # Some stuff happens here. Details not important.
```

I'd like to add a classmethod that accepts a string, i.e. the text that would be in the file opened by `__init__`.

```
    @classmethod
    def from_text(cls, text: str) -> 'Foo'
        stream = io.StringIO(text)
        cls.initialize(stream)  # This line doesn't quite make sense
```

I'm not sure how to deal with the fact that we need to call `initialize` inside `from_text`, but we don't have an instance yet.
There must be some way I can construct an instance of `Foo` that I can pass to `initialize`, but I'm not clear on how to do it.
How is this done?

Comment: To make a new instance, call `Foo()` or `cls()`.  You'd have to change your `__init__()` so that you could avoid opening a file by name in cases like this where you aren't dealing with an actual file.

Answer (score 0):

As @jasonharper pointed out you need you change your constructor to accept any file like object.

Then you could have something like the following:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(f: TextIO) -> None:
        self.initialize(f)

    def initialize(self, stream)
        pass  # Some stuff happens here. Details not important.

    @classmethod
    def from_text(cls, text: str) -> 'Foo'
        stream = io.StringIO(text)
        return cls(stream)

    @classmethod
    def from_filename(cls, filename: str) -> 'Foo'
        with open(filename) as f:
            return cls(f)
```

**EDIT:**
If you must keep the same constructor you could use a [named temporary file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) as in:

```
    @classmethod
    def from_text(cls, text: str) -> 'Foo'
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as f:
            f.write(text)
        return cls(f.name)
```

Note: the `delete=True` argument is set so that the read works in multiple platforms. Make sure to read the docs to understand the different options.